# method doesn't accept nullable date, why?

Tags: java

I have a method that has four parameter, two  of them is type dates, my problem is when dates are null, I have exception, my method does not accept nullable date, how do I fix that, this my code :

```
    Date StartDate=dateper1.getDate();
Date EndDate=dateper2.getDate();
System.out.println(StartDate);
m.SearchProduct(calcul, Designation,StartDate,EndDate);
```

method :

```
public void SearchProduct(JTable calcul,String Designation,Date StartDate, Date EndDate)
{
try
{
conn=con.Connect();
stmt =  conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rsDesignation=   stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM calcul WHERE designation='"+Designation+"' ");
ResultSet rsDate=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM calcul WHERE dateper<='"+EndDate+"' AND dateper>='"+StartDate+"'");
if(StartDate==null && EndDate==null )
this.GetAttribut(calcul, rsDesignation);    
if(   Designation.equals(" "))
this.GetAttribut(calcul, rsDate); 
stmt.close();
//c.commit();
conn.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: provide (or read) stacktraces - always

Comment: dateper1.getDate() back really date?? post full code.

Comment: Fix that by not allowing null dates! Why would you want that anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry dude, simple to handle. Change this line of yours:

```
ResultSet rsDate=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM calcul WHERE dateper<='"+EndDate+"' AND dateper>='"+StartDate+"'");
```

by the next ones:

```
Stringbuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM calcul");
if (EndDate != null && StartDate != null){
    sql.append(" WHERE dateper<='"+EndDate+"' AND dateper>='"+StartDate+"'");
else if (EndDate == null && StartDate != null){
    sql.append(" WHERE dateper>='"+StartDate+"'");
}else if (EndDate != null && StartDate == null){
    sql.append(" WHERE dateper<='"+EndDate+"'");
}
ResultSet rsDate=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Also, you may prefer moving the queries inside each condition, because looking at your code you just need to execute rsDate query when any date is not null. Like this:

```
if(StartDate==null && EndDate==null ){
    ResultSet rsDesignation=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM calcul WHERE designation='"+Designation+"' ");
    this.GetAttribut(calcul, rsDesignation);  
}  
if(Designation.equals(" ")){
    ResultSet rsDate=....; // The code above I wrote
    this.GetAttribut(calcul, rsDate); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing nulls to SQL. Your program actually receives this:

```
SELECT * FROM calcul WHERE dateper<='null' AND dateper>='null'
```

That's because when null objects are changed to String the result is `null` as a String (actual characters n,u,l,l). So database throws exception when it's compiling this query - because it doesn't make sense.

You have to handle nulls somehow in your code - it depends on what do you want to achieve.

Also, please note that the naming you are using is **not** recommended for Java language. You should consider naming your methods with *lowerCamelCase* not *UpperCamelCase*.

Here is pretty-formatted code:

```
Date startDate = dateper1.getDate();
Date endDate = dateper2.getDate();
System.out.println(startDate);
m.searchProduct(calcul, designation, startDate, endDate);

public void searchProduct(JTable calcul, String designation, Date startDate,   Date endDate)
{
    try {
        conn=con.connect();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsDesignation = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM calcul WHERE designation='" + designation + "'");
        ResultSet rsDate = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM calcul WHERE dateper<='" + endDate + "' AND dateper >= '" + startDate + "'");
        if(startDate  == null && endDate == null) {
            this.getAttribute(calcul, rsDesignation);
        }
        if(" ".equals(designation)) {
            this.getAttribute(calcul, rsDate); 
        }
        stmt.close();
        //c.commit();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Readbility is a very important aspect in programming. As you may notice, pretty-formatted code looks much more pleasent to the eye (and for a mind too ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rsDate=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM calcul WHERE dateper<='"+EndDate+"' AND dateper>='"+StartDate+"'");
```

throws a `NullPointerException` if `EndDate` or `StartDate` is `null`.

Add a `null` check or don't allow `null` dates like @fge say in comment.